# How to create a template from existing resources?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-cloudformation, terraform-provider-aws, infrastructure-as-code

I've heard about "CloudFormer" tool, to automatically generate a base template from existing resources on the cloud.
https://medium.com/@ridmag/how-to-use-aws-cloudformer-e8d848cfafe1

I can't find this tool in aws! Perhaps this is a old tool that has been removed?

I've heard about another not-Amazon product named "terraform.io" as well. Can Terraform do this? Can it produce a template (in its proprietary format and/or in the cloudformation format) as well?

Answer (score 3):

CoudFormer is no longer maintained and deprecated by AWS. Instead, [former2](https://former2.com/) can be used which is **open sourced**, developed by [AWS Hero](https://aws.amazon.com/developer/community/heroes/ian-mckay/) and used by AWS clients as explained in AWS blog:

- [How DNAnexus used the open source Former2 project to create infrastructure as code templates for their disaster recovery pipeline](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/opensource/how-dnanexus-used-the-open-source-former2-project-to-create-infrastructure-as-code-templates-for-their-disaster-recovery-pipeline/)